# "Oops! Something Bad Happened!" on Winter Bash leaderboard

Tags: bug, winter-bash, 500-server-error, winter-bash-2021

The [Winter Bash 2021 leaderboard](https://winterbash2021.stackexchange.com/leaderboard) gives a server error whenever it is visted:

> ## Oops! Something Bad Happened!
>
> We apologize for any inconvenience, but an unexpected error occurred while you were browsing our site. It’s not you, it’s us. This is our fault. Detailed information about this error has automatically been recorded and we have been notified.

Viewing [the leaderboard for a particular site](https://winterbash2021.stackexchange.com/leaderboard/meta.stackexchange.com) works correctly.

It should not do that. This happens for me regardless of if I am logged in.

---

Happening again! on 8:18 am
Tuesday, 21 December 2021

Comment: I don't doubt the validity of this bug report but I can't reproduce it. (But perhaps I'm hitting a different server node than you.)

Comment: @Glorfindel It works for me now too! Perhaps it was only a transient error.

Comment: Again! Same error

Comment: @Wolgwang I got it too, but it works now.